# How to dispaly product to related category using laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to show products related to the category. In my menu I have a list of categories if I click this category i want to see related products to this category. I'm just learning laravel can somebody help me out..

DATABASE:

```
-category: id, cate_name ,p_id

-product: has Category_id
```

Product model:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class product extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [ 'id', 'product_name', 'product_price', 'product_image', 
    'product_brand'];
}
```

Category model:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class category extends Model
{
    public $table = "category";
    public function childs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\category','p_id');
    }
}
```

Category  view:

```
<div class="nav-panel__nav-links nav-links">
    <ul class="nav-links__list">
        @foreach(App\category::with('childs')->where('p_id',0)->get() as $firstmenu)
        <li class="nav-links__item  nav-links__item--has-submenu ">
            <a id="cate" class="nav-links__item-link" href="{{$firstmenu->cate_name}}">
                <div class="nav-links__item-body">
                    {{$firstmenu->cate_name}}
                    <svg class="nav-links__item-arrow" width="9px" height="6px">
                        <use xlink:href="public/assets/images/sprite.svg#arrow-rounded-down-9x6"></use>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="nav-links__submenu nav-links__submenu--type--megamenu nav- 
    links__submenu--size--nl">
                <!-- .megamenu -->
                <div class="megamenu ">
                    <div class="megamenu__body">
                        <div class="row">
                            @foreach($firstmenu->childs as $secondmenu)
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <ul class="megamenu__links megamenu__links--level--0">
                                    <li class="megamenu__item  megamenu__item--with-submenu ">
                                        <a href="">{{$secondmenu->cate_name}}</a>
                                        <ul class="megamenu__links megamenu__links--level--1">

                                            @foreach($secondmenu->childs as $thirdmenu)
                                            <li class="megamenu__item"><a href="">{{$thirdmenu->cate_name}}</a></li>
                                            @endforeach

                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- .megamenu / end -->
            </div>
        </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to show product to related category using laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59247441/i-want-to-show-product-to-related-category-using-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Dependiong on your relation type (One-Many, Many-Many, One-One) you can create relations,
you can use [this article](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships)